# How to populate a form from a listview on tap in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a form widget, a list widget, and a "wrapper" widget or in other words, a parent/container widget. So to give an idea of the widget tree, it is as such.

- Parent/Container Widget

  - Form Widget
  - Button Widget
  - List Widget

Notice that the form, buttons and list widget are all siblings, inside of the parent/container widget. What I want to happen, is tap on a list item in the list widget, and populate the form widget with the data that gets passed from the list widget.

Here is my parent widget.

```
import 'package:andplus_flutter_7_gui/model/user.dart';
import 'package:andplus_flutter_7_gui/services/user_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'crud_form.dart';
import 'crud_list.dart';

class Crud extends StatefulWidget {
  Crud({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  _CrudContainerState createState() => _CrudContainerState();
}

class _CrudContainerState extends State<Crud> {
  List<User> users;
  User user = User();
  UserService userService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (userService == null) {
      userService = UserService(user);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    userService.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
                        return CrudForm(
                          user: snapshot.data,
                          onUserAdded: (user) {
                            userService.addUser(user);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      stream: userService.userObservable,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text("Future button widget"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snap) {
                        return CrudList(
                          onUserSelected: userService.userSelected,
                          users: snap.data,
                        );
                      },
                      stream: userService.usersObservable,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onEditUser(User user) {
    setState(() {
      user = user;
    });
  }
}
```

The above widget wraps the three widgets I mentioned.

Here are the children widget:

Form:

```
import 'package:andplus_flutter_7_gui/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CrudForm extends StatefulWidget {
  CrudForm({Key key, this.onUserAdded, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  final User user;
  final void Function(User user) onUserAdded;

  _CrudFormState createState() => _CrudFormState(user: user);
}

class _CrudFormState extends State<CrudForm> {
  _CrudFormState({this.user});

  User user = User();
  var _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
              child: Form(
                key: _key,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "First Name",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                initialValue: widget.user?.firstName == null ||
                                        widget.user.firstName.isEmpty
                                    ? user.firstName
                                    : widget.user.firstName,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return "First name is required";
                                  }

                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    user.firstName = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Last Name",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Last name is required";
                                  }

                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    user.lastName = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          "Save",
                        ),
                        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (!_key.currentState.validate()) {
                            return;
                          }
                          _key.currentState.save();
                          widget.onUserAdded(
                            new User(
                              firstName: user.firstName,
                              lastName: user.lastName,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my list widget.

```
import 'package:andplus_flutter_7_gui/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CrudList extends StatefulWidget {
  CrudList({Key key, this.users, this.onUserSelected}) : super(key: key);

  final List<User> users;

  final SelectUser onUserSelected;

  _CrudListState createState() => _CrudListState();
}

class _CrudListState extends State<CrudList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.users?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var user = widget.users[index];
          return ListTile(
            key: Key(index.toString()),
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              print("${widget.users[index]} $index");
              widget.onUserSelected(widget.users[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef void SelectUser(User user);
```

And just for further context, here is my user service, responsible for adding the objects to the stream, and using the stream builder within rxdart to notify of state changes.

```
import 'package:andplus_flutter_7_gui/model/user.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class UserService {
  User _editedUser = User();
  List<User> _users = <User>[];
  BehaviorSubject<User> _userSubject;
  BehaviorSubject<List<User>> _usersSubject;

  UserService(this._editedUser) {
    _userSubject = BehaviorSubject<User>.seeded(_editedUser);
    _usersSubject = BehaviorSubject<List<User>>.seeded(_users);
  }

  Observable<List<User>> get usersObservable => _usersSubject.stream;
  Observable<User> get userObservable => _userSubject.stream;

  addUser(User user) {
    _users.add(user);
    _usersSubject.add(_users);
  }

  dispose() {
    _userSubject.close();
    _usersSubject.close();
  }

  void userSelected(User user) {
    _editedUser = user;
    _userSubject.add(_editedUser);
  }
}
```

What am I missing? It looks like my widget rebuilds, and tries to set the initial value in the form when I tap the user in the list widget. But the actual field doesn't get updated and I'm not sure why.

I'd appreciate any documentation or articles on how to better approach data and state management between sibling widgets within the flutter framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar use case that I tried to implement locally. What I'm doing here is I generate TextFormFields dynamically and assign TextEditingController.

```dart
Column textField(int n) {
  List<Widget> listForm = [];
  while (n > 0) {
    var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    listForm.add(
      TextFormField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        onTap: () {
          _selectedField = textEditingController;
        },
      ),
    );
    n--;
  }
  return Column(children: listForm);
}
```

Clicking a ListView item updates the text of the currently selected TextFormField.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    debugPrint('Selected $index!');
    if (_selectedField != null) {
      _selectedField!.value = TextEditingValue(text: 'Item $index');
    }
  },
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text('Item $index'),
  ),
);
```

Complete sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController? _selectedField;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: textField(3)),
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: listItems()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column textField(int n) {
    List<Widget> listForm = [];
    while (n > 0) {
      var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
      listForm.add(
        TextFormField(
          controller: textEditingController,
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint('Current Controller: $textEditingController');
            _selectedField = textEditingController;
          },
        ),
      );
      n--;
    }
    return Column(children: listForm);
  }

  ListView listItems() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (_selectedField != null) {
              _selectedField!.value = TextEditingValue(text: 'Item $index');
            }
          },
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: Demo]